# Putting the text of a UITextField into a UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipod

Im trying to put the text from a textfield into a UIAlertView, but it's not shown. It is just showing blank.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Kik" message:self.kik.text delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Got it!" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];
```

Comment: Have you tried to `NSLog(@"%@",self.kik.text);` and see what you get? If it is nil or blank then that is your problem right there.

Comment: Thanks that fixed everything! Turns out I was shooting a blank. @Jsdodgers

Answer (score 0):

You should try,

```
if ( [self.kik.text length])
{
UIAlertView *alert = [UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Kik" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.kik.text] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Got it!" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];
}
else
{
UIAlertView *alert = [UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Kik" message:@"Please enter a valid string" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Got it!" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];

}
```

Check..